# How can I make load test in the react-native mobileapp with 100 users (Any tools to run the load test for RN apps)

Tags: react-native

How can I load test the react-native apps?

I am using RN version 0.59.9 and how can i run the load test with 100 users.

Answer (score 0):

Every single React Native apps running on single device, unlike web development, there's no single "web-server" to handle all the load. So logically speaking the performance whether your React Native running on one device, or one million device, in terms of performance should be exactly the same.

However, if you wish to improve React Native performance, you can refer to https://reactnative.dev/docs/performance.html and improving in other area, such as improving frame rates, slow navigator transition and so on